# Navigation to a SAPUI5 Application using url link from an external application

Tags: javascript, url, sapui5

I have got a new scenario in which a link is provided and on click, it will navigate to a sapui5 application. I have to read the parameters passed in the url and decide a particular navigation to a view/page. How can i achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try out so far and what of those attempts did not work? You also did not provide and code examples yet for how you access the parameters in your application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We tend to expect folks who post questions like yours have at least *tried* some coding solution; we are good at finding errors and other issues in posted code, but not so hot at posting code from a null base.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, RTFM, you should realy do the walktrhough before beginning developping for SAPUI5.

[SAPUI5 walkthrough](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db) What you asked is nicely described in there...
[Routing with parameters](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/2366345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef)

But since I am a nice person here a TL;DR; version:

You have to add routes to your router defining the url parameters you want/need:

In manifest:

```
...,
routes: [
                {
                    "name": "personDetailView",
                    "pattern": "person/detail/{id}",
                    "titleTarget": "",
                    "target": [
                        "PersonDetailView"
                    ]
                },
...
]
```

and then add the target:

```
targets: [
                "FuelRequestNew": {
                    "clearControlAggregation": false,
                    "viewName": "Detail",
                    "viewId": "PersonDetailView",
                    "viewPath": "namespace.workspace.view.personDetail"
                },
...
]
```

That way upon entering the url (in this example domain.com/person/detail/{id}), the router takes you to the right page.

To get the {id} passed you will need to attach the onRouteMattched event to the view.

In onInit of the view:

```
this.getRouter().getRoute("personDetailView").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
```

and define the callback methode onRouteMatched:

```
_onRouteMatched: function (oEvent) {
            var sPersonId= oEvent.getParameter("arguments").id; // 'id' name defined in routes!
            // Do stuff with url parameters
}
```